# Ser.write() ,when checked shows only the length

Tags: gpio, python, serial, uart

I have used `a=ser.write("TEST".encode())` in my code to send data using UART gpio in Rpi.
The code shows no error but when I print a,it gives me the length only.
Actually i am trying to interface Rpi and Nordic Nrf52832 using UART.
I want to send data to nrf from pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What return value do you expect instead?

It is normal that a write call returns the number of bytes written, a successful write returns the number of bytes it was supposed to write.

You can use a check similar to this

```
if (ser.write (data, length) != length)
  // Write not successful
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.I basically had a doubt whether data is being transmitted or not. How to check that?